# MS VC2010 - path with slashes in both directions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, path

I'm getting this error in visual c++.  I've gotten it before with slashes point in the wrong direction.

Here is the error:

```
Unable to start program
'C:\Develop\QxOrm\1.2.4\QxOrm\tes\qxDllSample\dll1\debug/dll1.dll'
```

Any ideas what might be causing that?

Comment: You cannot start a DLL, only an EXE

Answer (score 3):

\t is an escape code for a tab. Use \\ to escape the backslash, or use all forward slashes.